# How to make laravel run on my local server

Tags: laravel-5

I bought a laravel script, is working online and is not running locally. when i run it locally i see  error Fatal error: Interface `'Psr\Container\ContainerInterface'` not found in `C:\xampp72\htdocs\investment\cronlab\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Contracts\C
ontainer\Container.php` on line 8 but online is ok

**my composer.json file**

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0.0",
        "adamwathan/eloquent-oauth-l5": "^0.5.2",
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.1",
        "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
        "graham-campbell/markdown": "^9.0",
        "greggilbert/recaptcha": "^2.2",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "paypal/rest-api-sdk-php": "*",
        "unicodeveloper/laravel-paystack": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "~1.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
             "Meow\\Halum\\": "vendor/meow/halum/src"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    }
}
```

Comment: have you run `composer install` command?

Comment: Is this solution helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46454907/php-error-at-runtime-interface-psr-container-containerinterface-not-found